# Cannot make a sum of multiple operators

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sum, factorial

I am trying to make a simulation that contains a summation with a fitting parameter m.

for example, if I add a value of m = 1 I can make up to 70 sums but if I add m = 5. I can only make 19 sums. and this error appears.

TypeError: ufunc 'add' output (typecode 'O') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'd') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''

My code is as follows

```
from scipy.special import factorial2

m = 5

theta = np.linspace(0, 1.5, 100)

def I(n):
    it = 0
    for t in range(n+1):
        it += ((2**t)*(m**t)*(np.cos(theta)**(2*t)))/factorial2(2*t+1)
    return it

Itheta= I(20)
```

I have tried to see if the error lay on the factorial operator but if you remove it from the loop the error remains.

Comment: What does the function ```factorial2``` do? Could you update your post to an MRE?

Comment: I found it was ```from scipy.special import factorial2```. To fix your error, replace ```it = 0``` with ```it = np.zeros(100)```.

Comment: yes `factorial2` comes from that library. well I just try to do as you said substituting ìt = 0`but did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was another quirk with the += operator. [Be careful with it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGveIvwwSq4). Following up on my comments:

```
from scipy.special import factorial2
import numpy as np

m = 5

theta = np.linspace(0, 1.5, 100)

def I(n):
    it = np.zeros(100)
    for t in range(n+1):
        it = it + ((2**t)*(m**t)*(np.cos(theta)**(2*t)))/factorial2(2*t+1)
    return it

Itheta = I(20)

print(Itheta)
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##RY5BjsMgDEX3PoWXQEdpmlE3I/UAOQZiyBSpGAvcRXr51Ek6LQuDHt9Pn2e5FvpelqmWjC0knrvGMSR/w5S5VMHJBylVwQAvQvfMM/qGxAAZL3gGkGsUr0/i7paosQ/R9F946s46@t4C/MYJR0P2B1BPkj38iLU0syVWPJWKgomwevqLhg6nV/69o@OAxgzOiXUm75eKgmq2EtY5/RVr7fFTfSXq2lQ1yr2SigDG/9qjGdaOXBOJ2aldlic)

Comment: Interesting video, I use Python daily and had never given `+=` much thought.

Answer (score 0):

The error does not occur anymore in the following way (i.e. do not use `it += ..`).

```
def I(n):
    it = 0
    for t in range(n+1):
        it = it + ((2**t)*(m**t)*(np.cos(theta)**(2*t)))/factorial2(2*t+1)

    return it
```

Interestingly, `it += ..` does not lead to an error when using the following steps.

```
def I(n):
    it = 0
    for t in range(n+1):
        a = 2**t
        b = m**t
        c = np.cos(theta)**(2*t)
        d = factorial2(2*t+1)
        it += a*(b*c)/d

    return it
```

Unfortunately, I can't really explain to you why this is the case.

Comment: I just see, @Tempman383838 might have an explanation for this (although I'm curious why my second example works then).